# How to calculate values based on spearman

Tags: r, statistics

I have three columns numberCounts sequenced, numberCounts RefSeq, and RPKM values, how to calculated each value for the genes using spearman correlation?

This is my code to calculated spearman:

```
fig5cwithoutdesc <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/fig5cwithoutdesc.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)
head(fig5cwithoutdesc)
xRPKM<-fig5cwithoutdesc$RPKM
yRefSeq<-fig5cwithoutdesc$RefSeq
cor(xRPKM, yRefSeq, method="spearman")
```

Comment: Why are you using `method="pearson"` instead of `method="spearman"`?

Comment: Corrected, thank you @dcarlson !

Comment: In your question you say EACH value. It isn't clear what multiple values you are trying to produce. Also check that it imported correctly. I'm seeing mostly NA after row 450 of 2209.

Comment: @andrea this can be cleaned by something such as `fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs))`

Answer (score 0):

if you sure, that you need to calculate "spearman":
cor(fig5cwithoutdesc$RPKM, fig5cwithoutdesc$RefSeq, method="spearman")
and then you'll get your output.

you can also use cor.test()- function (if you need use it with Significance)

Comment: I want the ranking the correlation for each ID @TonyBony